# Is it possible to invalidate cookies before the expiration date?

Tags: javascript, cookies

Fairly general question, but: say I have a top of the web browser banner with your typical click-to-dismiss Javascript; that script sets a browser cookie to not show that banner for 1 month, even after closing the browser.

I don't want the banner to be annoying and don't want users to have to constantly click to dismiss. (And I know if the user clears cookies, the banner will reappear).

But say, once in a while, after two weeks, I need to show a different banner to all users, even those with the cookie that doesn't expire for two more weeks.

Question: how can I invalidate all those browser cookies that have two weeks left to live? And show the banner again? And set a new cookie for a month?

Do I need to change the name of the cookie in my script server-side? Is there another way without changing the name?

Edit:

I need to figure out a "one step" method, if possible, as I need to add a feature to the backend of a website to allow a user to easily change the cookie's parameters to force a new cookie in the end user browser. So I'm thinking changing the name of the cookie as a user option; that will show a new cookie to the browser and leave the old cookie in place. Messy, yes, but that's quick and easy.

Comment: Just set the cookie's expiration date to a time in the past and it will delete the cookie. Then create a new cookie.

Comment: If the feature is going to be added to the "backend", how will the user be able to invoke it?  If you just make some sort of button that says "Reset" and have that button set an expiration date in the past, the problem is solved.

Comment: I was thinking of a metabox that stored the cookie's name in the database; once the cookie's name is changed, that effectively resets the cookie. If I change the cookie date to the past, that invalidates the current cookie in all users browsers, but I still need to change the date forward again to show the new banner for am month, and that doesn't clear all cookies on the all users' browsers.

Comment: I think you are overthinking this. If you are going to store information in a database about a cookie, why not just ditch the cookie and use the database to persist the data?  Expiring the cookie and setting a new one is the simplest approach.

Comment: I still need a cookie in the public's browser to close the banner and keep it closed for the duration of the cookie, or expire that cookie ahead of the expiration date from the server side.